# Why search engines can't index Ajax sites directly?

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, search, search-engine

I understand as a (GWT developer) that Ajax sites renders page dynamically, and for instance the site i made is single page and contained tabs to render "pages" like "home", "about us", "products", etc.

However those pages are usually incorporated with a hash (`#`) and that if I access say, `http://example.com#HomePage` or `#Products` it will would render the page and the contents "eventually"...

Now if I put my products page site on my crawlable static blog site for example: `http://example.com#Products` if I click through this site then my site will render the products eventually after some ajax calls.

However, if I check the "page source" of the site from the browser the page is still the same html "empty from ajax content"; is this the reason why ajax site can't be indexed? Search engines don't put the URL they crawl in a HTML unit so they can render the page and not just get the static page?

Anyway, I saw implementations to workaround this issue, to use a external "crawler" service as part of the ajax site, however is there no solution that does not require to setup such external service / server?

Comment: Google has published a proposal in 2009 which explains how AJAX website could be created which can be indexed by their search spider, but I don't know if this was ever implemented: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

Comment: They did implement it. They're now pushing towards server-rendered content and `pushState()` (we're not there yet with GWT, but GWT is designed for apps, not sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should know is that crawlers don't execute javascript on the page, but there is a way to make page crawlable (to show crawler that your application use AJAX).

Example(google crawler):

You should first indicate to the crawler that your site supports the AJAX crawling scheme by adding special token to application AJAX links. After that, crawler will transform that URL and with transformed URL call your server. Server should return HTML snapshot (generated HTML) which represents the HTML content that is created when user in browser load page with AJAX. On the end you can use [Fetch as Google tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587) to test what will google crawler receive when call your AJAX links. In depth explanation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

I don't work with GWT but maybe you can some specific solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/CrawlerSupport).

Comment: Hello pedjaradenkovic. Please note that link-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow because they can easily fall victim to link rot. Linking to your source when you make a statement is appreciated, but please always write at least a synopsis of the link content.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Please note that the advice given in the first link (to Google) has [significant drawbacks](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: @Philipp Thank you for suggest. I will pay more attention next time.

Comment: @pedjaradenkovic note that you can still edit your answer. Your links have useful content, when you edit your answer and describe what they suggest with your own words, I will consider to upvote your answer.

Comment: @Quentin When I understand your link correctly, its main argument is "Search engines don't understand it". The link by pedjaradenkovic describes how to do it so that search engines *do* understand it, so I can't really follow your line of reasoning.

Comment: @Philipp — That isn't the argument of that link at all. The argument is that the whole approach is fragile and prone to breaking.

Comment: @pedjaradenkovic Thanks for the link, right I understand this scenario that a URL with hash-bang (#!) is considered as Ajax crawlable, and that the crawler expects a service that provides a HTML snapshot of the page.

Comment: @pedjaradenkovic I guess for some reason, Search engines don't want to do their own HTML snapshot of an ajax page

Comment: @xybrek, as Quentin said in his post, executing JS requires a lot of resources so I assume that crawlers don't JS on your page until you suggest them to do that. I'm glad that links helped you, but i have edited answer for next readers as Philipp suggested. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I check the "page source" of the site from the browser the page is still the same html "empty from ajax content"; is this the reason why ajax site can't be indexed? Search engines don't put the URL they crawl in a HTML unit so they can render the page and not just get the static page?

Yes, sites that depend on Ajax to pull in content are depending on JavaScript to pull in content and search engine indexing bots do not (in general) execute JavaScript since:

- It requires much more CPU/RAM to do so
- It is very hard to determine what interactions will pull in new content and which will do other things

> Anyway, I saw implementations to workaround this issue, to use a external "crawler" service as part of the ajax site, however is there no solution that does not require to setup such external service / server?

Don't depend on JavaScript in the first place. Build a site that works with regular links. Layer JavaScript on top if you want to. Use [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to update the address bar with the real URL when new content is pulled in.

In short, follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)